# Just refresh the div after login or logout

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a web project. In the layout page, we have a div for login/logout

```
<div id="login">
@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
    //// something to show id and logout option
} else {
    <form method="post">
    //// some input boxes for id and pass
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="submit"/>
    </form>
}
</div>
```

So, after user login, all I want is refresh this div without reload the whole page, and so that this div will show id and logout option.

I searched online, and people use .reload from ajax. But in those cases, there are new stuff to be put in the .load(), and my case just want to refresh the div without any new stuff. Can I just use .load() without put anything in () to get the div refreshed?

Thanks!
Zeyu

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Tried, but nothing happened. If I refresh the whole page, I can see change, which means login function works, but .load() not...

Comment: What `.load`? I don't see it in your code. Can you show what you have actually tried, and where it went wrong?

Comment: can you post the javascript that handles the form submission?